# What is the cost of calling withColumn on Dataset

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I am staring to work with Datasets after several projects I worked with RDDs. I am using Java for development.

As far as I understand columns are immutable - there is no map function for column and the standard way to map column is adding a column with `withColumn`.

My question is what is really happening when I call withColumn? is there a performance penalty? should I try to make as few `withColumn` calls as possible or it doesn't matter?

Piggybacked question: Is there any performance penalty when I call any other row/column creation function such as explode or pivot?

Comment: For withColumn, very little, I guess. It's a change In metadata. Pivot can be only used after grouping the dataset so it's expensive.

Comment: Explode can be very slow in Spark 2 prior to Spark 2.2 : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-21657

Answer (score 1):

The performance of the various functions to interact with a DataFrame are all fast enough that you will never have a problem (or really notice them).

This will make more sense if you understand how spark executes the transormations you define in your driver.  When you call the various transformation functions (**withColumn**, **select**, etc) Spark isn't actually doing anything immediately.  It just registers what operations you want to run in it's execution plan.  Spark doesn't start computations on your data until you call an **action**, typically to get results or write out data.

Knowing all the operations you want to run allows spark to perform optimizations on the execution plan before actually running it.  For example, imagine you use **withColumn** to create a new column, but then drop that column before you write the data out to a file.  Spark knows that it never actually needs to compute that column.

The things that will typically determine the performance of your driver are:

1. How many wide transformations (shuffles of data between executors) are there and how much data is being shuffled
2. Do I have any expensive transformation functions

For your extra question about explode and pivot:

- Explode creates new rows but is a narrow transformation.  It can change the partitions in place without needing to move data between executors.  This means it is relatively cheap to perform.  There is an exception to this if you have very large arrays you are exploding as Raphael pointed out in the comments.
- Pivot requires a groupBy operation which is a wide transformation.  It must send data from every executor to every other executor to ensure that all the data for a given key is in the same partition.  This is an expensive operation because of all the extra network traffic required.

Comment: with "shallow" I think you mean "narrow"? Never heard of shallow transformations..... Note that explode is very inefficient for large arrays in Spark 2.0/2.1 : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-16998 and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-21657

Comment: Yeah, shallow was a typo.  That's fixed and updated to include your explode comment.  Thanks!